# How to transform an array to string via PHP

Tags: php, arrays, excel, string

I sit in Excel with the following problem:

I have an array that can contain one or more measures (multiselection from user) I want to get this array and transform it into a string with some added PERL expressions. I want the resulting string to be written in another array.

> Sample input (the array can store from 1 up to arround 200 values):

```
{"KPI","Parameters","Personnel costs", "Fixed costs", "Building costs"}
```

> Desired output:

```
^KPI$|^Parameters$|^Personnel costs$|^Fixed costs$|^Building costs$
```

> or just:

```
KPI$|^Parameters$|^Personnel costs$|^Fixed costs$|^Building costs
```

So far I have this and it doesn't work:

```
<?php
function transform ()
{  
    $s = activesheet();
    $awb = activeworkbook();
    $PickList = array($awb->names->item('lstMeasureEDN')->value);
    $String = implode("|",$PickList);   

setRange( 'rngAtoS', $String );
}
?>
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample input and expected output?

Comment: You can try serialize($String); or json_encode($String);

Comment: `implode` should do just fine for what you want. my guess is that `$pickList` is not what you expect it to be, could you provide the contents of the variable?

Comment: @PeterM right now it is: {"KPI","Parameters","Personnel costs"}

Comment: Hmm, mind adding the results of `var_dump($PickList)` to the question?

Comment: @PeterM It is blank.... The "$PickList = array($awb->names->item('lstMeasureEDN')->value);" statement doesn't seem to parse the value.

Comment: So I answer how to modify array and not about the Excel one. After you able to get  string from the Excel I will answer again

Comment: @givnv Then there is your problem :-) Like David mentioned after that PHP's `implode` function should do the trick.

Comment: @PeterM yes, that is the problem. Do you have any idea how to parse that value into my php programme? It is stored as a named range in Excel.

Comment: @givnv Not with the currently supplied information, mind sharing `var_dump($awb->names->item('lstMeasureEDN'))`?

Comment: @PeterM the var_dump just come out blank.

Comment: You should debug the function ‘activeworkbook()’ it does not seem to return any results.